# VBScript: Wait for database execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I connect my script with an MSSQL database using `"ADODB.Connection".`

Afterwards I'm copying one table to another table (works fine):

```
Call oDBConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO " & sTargetTable & "SELECT * FROM " & sSourceTable)
```

afterwards I want to delete all entries of `sSourceTable` (works also fine):

```
Call oDBConnection.Execute("DELETE FROM " & sSourceTable )
```

My question is: Does the second query wait till the first query is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General,
the Execute call will return when the SQL (the INSERT in this case) is finished.

```
Call oDBConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO " & sTargetTable & " SELECT * FROM " & sSourceTable)
```

Hence the second Execute will be called after the first is finished.

```
Call oDBConnection.Execute("DELETE FROM " & sSourceTable )
```

Comment: Hi @jsodemann, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.